# Console command ./craft db/restore expects "info" table. Why?

Tags: craft3, console, commands

Why does the console command `./craft db/restore` expect the info table to exist and contain a row?
There is also no option to ignore a non-existing info or empty info table.

When we create automated restore procedures via Jenkins, this causes the restore to fail, because the DB is e.g. empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Not a direct solution, but maybe a workaround would be to run [install/craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#install) in your CD pipeline (would need to specify all optional parameters to avoid it needing input). This will create all missing tables, so the restore should work.

Comment: There's an issue for this here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7028. I just tested it on the latest Craft and while you do get that message, the database is also properly restored, so it's more of a UI issue. Did you verify the database was properly restored on Jenkins? Going to go ahead and vote to close here, but feel free to add a comment on the existing GH issue.

Comment: Hmm. We had the issue at a customer's staging installation yesterday, where the info table existed, but was empty, and the restore failed. Only after manually inserting the single row in the info table I was able to restore the full database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is confirmed and solved in 3.6.18